# Facing Issues In GridView

Tags: android, gridview, uiview

Here I am working on a application where I have to use GridView to display some images according to customers requirement.

In that GridView I am displaying 2 rows and 2 columns at a time, So that 4 images can be visible at a time. Now user want to do some changes and want me create a **EditText** in which he can enter the number and **according to that number, GridView should change its column and rows .**

Is it possible as I have gone through many online examples and what all I got is change the GridView at run time but with the fixed predefined number of rows and columns. But I didn't find any example like change the GridView from EditText at run time.

and type of help will be appreciable.

Comment: use custom adapter and pass an argument of number of images from the user in the constructor. use it for n number of images that you want to show.

Comment: Actually there is a way to handle this. You can take maximum number of columns/rows at the time of initialization. Then you can apply android:visibility="gone" property for those columns/rows, you don't want. This way you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment you can use custom baseadapter for your gridview and take the number of images as an argument in the constructor of the adapter class. Below is the code snippet that you can use to achieve this.

**Custom BaseAdapter**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Context context;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final int numbers;

public Adapter(Context context, int numberOfImages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.numbers = numberOfImages;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //You need to return the numberOfImages here for 
    //the adapter to determine how many view you need to create.
    return numbers;
}

private class viewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView image_desc;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        holder = new viewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.image_desc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_desc);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add_person);
        holder.image_desc.setText("change");
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

**Your main activity:**  In this activity you need to ask the user to enter the number of images they want to see. I have not added any kind of validation or error message when user does not enter a value but instead I have catched the possible error and used it to assign default value. You can apply other kind of logics here according to your requirement.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText text;
Button button;
int number;
private static final String NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = "numbers";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    try {
        number = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

        // if user enters 0 or negative number then the default value is set
        // to 2
        if (number < 1) {
            number = 2;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // if user doesn't enter anything then code will catch 
        // classCastException and assign 2 as default value here
        number = 2;
    }
    // start this intent by putting this number in the bundle
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(NUMBER_OF_IMAGES, number);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

**Second Activity:**  this is the activity where you define and initialise your gridview and adapter. make sure you retrieve the bundle from previous activity and retrieve the number entered by user properly.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grids);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int numbers = bundle.getInt(MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_IMAGES);

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    // depending upon your requirement you can also add logic here to set
    // the number of columns based on the number entered by the user
    setColumns(numbers);
    adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), numbers);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Method to set the number of columns depending upon user input for desired
 * grids. other attributes for the grid view can also be set her such as
 * width, height, background etc.
 * 
 * @param number
 */
public void setColumns(int number) {
    if (number > 0 && number < 10) {
        grid.setNumColumns(2);
    } else if (number >= 10 && number < 20) {
        grid.setNumColumns(4);
    } else {
        grid.setNumColumns(5);
    }
}
}
```

**NOTE:**  This is not highly optimised code for performance but just provides an example of how the required functionality can be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for your precious reply, I'll check the code and let you know that what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Based on number of rows and columns entered by ueser you can calculate number of items to show, pass that much no of item to your adapter and for setting column number You can try `gridView.setNumColumns(numColumns);`. Number of rows will be adjusted accordingly.